# Explanation of C++ class constructor syntax?

Tags: c++

Reading through *The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition*, there's a class defined like so

```
class Vector
{
    private:
        int sz;
        double *a;
    public:
        Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
}
```

I'm a bit confused on how this constructor syntax works. I believe `Vector(int s)` is creating a constructor function that takes one parameter `s`, and that it initializes `elem` and `sz`. But why is there a `:`?  I thought functions bodies were surrounded by `{}`? And so what do the empty braces `{}` at the end serve?

Comment: Doesn't the book explain the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is used to "initialize" the members of a class (this method is also called 
member initialization list)

there is a major difference between using `:` and function body  `{}`

initiallizer list `:` initialize the members of class, whereas ,constructor body `{}` assigns the value to the members of the class.

the difference may not seem very big but it is actually the only way to initialize the `const` data type and `reference` data type members (which can only be initialized during declaration )

So when you do this

```
class Test
{
const int i; const string str;
public:
Test(int x, string y):i{x},str{y};
}
```

This would work, but if you try to assign values to `const int i` and `const string str` by writing their code in the body of constructor, it would lead to a result

> And so what do the empty braces {} at the end serve?

nothing it is just compulsory to put those braces (even if it is empty)

They can basically serve as a function when you create an object of the class inside the `main` function and pass it the required arguments.

Answer (score 5):

`:` is called an initialiser list, which is used to quickly and concisely set values for the member variables when the constructor is called.

`{}` is the constructor's method body. Since the constructor is similar to a method, there has to be a body present for the code to compile. Since there is no need for any code in there, an empty body is used so the function does nothing.

Comment: Also the initialiser list happens before anything in the constructor body of the constructor gets executed

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I must've missed it reading through. I'll accept your answer once the cool down runs out.

Comment: Is the initializer list unique to constructor functions only? For example, can I use it for a regular function?

Comment: No, initialiser lists are only available on class constructors.

Answer (score 2):

This is initialization with [Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).