# Classes not giving required output in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have created a class name `Employee` and inside that I have declared a function and two variable(name ,age) . After creating a variable `x`  I am not getting the name insted getting `empty name` and `age =0`

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    void print(){
     cout<<"Name:"<<name<<endl;
     cout<<"Age:"<<age<<endl;
    }
    
    Employee(string name,int age){
        name = name;
        age=age;
    }
    

};
int main(){

    Employee x=Employee("chang",33);
    x.print();
     return 0;
}
```

**Expected:**
name:Chang
age :33

**OutPut:**
name:
age :0

Can Someone tell me what is the reason behind it.

Comment: You are assigning vars to themselves `name = name;
        age=age;`. Try `this->name = name;
        this->age=age;`

Comment: Or try using a [member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157938/explanation-of-c-class-constructor-syntax) instead of performing a default initialization followed by an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Employee(string name, int age) {
    name = name;
    age = age;
}
```

you are **not** modifying the class members, but the parameters instead.

You have three ways to solve this problem:

- use `this->` to precisely target the right variables.

  ```
  Employee(string name, int age) {
     this->name = name;
     this->age = age;
  }
  ```
- use an [initialisation list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

  ```
  Employee(string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {

  }
  ```
- don't use any constructor, but use [`brace initialization`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) instead:

  ```
  int main() {
      Employee x = Employee{ "chang", 33 };
      x.print();
  }
  ```

I would personally use option three with the braces, as it's the most efficient to write.

---

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why you shouldn't be `using namespace std;`

Comment: I know it's obvious but the fourth option is to choose different names for the parameters. Might not occur to a newbie.